# Test project asks for adding a reference from the main project even though main project is referenced

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have written a test method to test one of my main projects methods. In my Test Project I have referenced my main project. But since I am using some of its classes in my test project, Visual Studio is telling that:

> The type 'XYZ' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You
>   must add a reference to assembly 'XYZ, version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

[image]

So, I guess my question is, why when we have already added a reference to our main project, do we still need to separately add all libraries it refers to in the test project as well?

Comment: Please show us the source code of `XYZ`.

Comment: @mjwills added a snapshot. Please check.

Comment: @mjwills This is an ASP.NET MVC5 project using Entity Framework 6.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly yes.

Add NuGet package "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" to your unit test project:

[image]

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/

If you remove the package you get the error again.

This action can fix situation I can reproduce by following three steps:

1) Create ASP.Net Web Application: [image]

and validate that packages.config contains:

`<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />`

2) Create Unit Test Project:

[image]

and add following test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var controller = new HomeController();
    var target = controller.Index();
}
```

3) Upon compile I get this error:

> The type 'ActionResult' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
>   UnitTestProject1 UnitTest1.cs

Comment: Thank you. But I don't think it stops there. When I test one of my methods, the test project does not seem to find the connection string to the database in the main project. I get the error `Bookshelf.Controllers.Tests.BooksControllerTests.ReturnBookWithNegativeIdTest threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named 'BookshelfConnection' could be found in the application config file.
` Does it not make writing test method a time-consuming chore? I was under the impression that once adding reference to the main project, the test project get that from there.

Comment: Here it is similar - you need to re-define connection string - it can/should be different from your prod DB - in your unit test project App.config I agree initial setup is time consuming. Perhaps try to think about mock/"fake" DB data?

Comment: Sounds reasonable.